web worker not responding instantly
I have a next js project and in that i have this fn that i run on, onKeyDownCapture
NOTE-  the Fn works fine when its being executed on the main thread in the same file but when i move it to the web worker that is when the problem arises.
the worker and the main thread are successfully connected and send messages to and fro, have verified this
Now as we know the communication of the main thread with the worker is asynchronous, so i guess that might be causing the problem, that even though the worker returns true when the computation is done because its async we're kinda not being able to see its effect on the main thread
THE FN normally on the main thread (just for simplified context)
  const handleBackspace1 = useCallback(
    throttle((event, editor) => {
      if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
        const cursorPosition = editor.getTextCursorPosition();

        if (
          (cursorPosition.block.type === "paragraph" && cursorPosition.block.content.length === 0) &&
          customComponentsRef.current.includes(cursorPosition?.prevBlock?.type)
        ) {
          editor.setTextCursorPosition(cursorPosition.prevBlock, "end");
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }, 150), 
    []
  );

the actual web worker implementation part ->
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {

      workerRef.current = new Worker(new URL('../../../../Workers/BackspaceWorkerForEditor.js', import.meta.url));

      return () => {
        workerRef.current.terminate();
      };
    }
  }, []);

FN WITH THE WEB WORKER
  const handleBackspace = (event) => {
    console.log('1');
    if (event.key === 'Backspace' && typeof window !== 'undefined' && router.isReady) {
      console.log('2');
      const cursorPosition = editor.getTextCursorPosition();

      if (workerRef.current) {
        workerRef.current.postMessage({
          cursorPosition,
          customComponents: customComponentsRef.current,
        });

        workerRef.current.onmessage = function (e) {
          const { shouldPreventDefault, prevBlock } = e.data;
          console.log(shouldPreventDefault);

          if (shouldPreventDefault) {
            console.log('prevent default', shouldPreventDefault);
            editor.setTextCursorPosition(prevBlock, "end");
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        };
      }
    }
  };

the woker script
function handleMessage(event) {
  const { cursorPosition, customComponents } = event.data;
  if (
    cursorPosition.block.type === "paragraph" &&
    cursorPosition.block.content.length === 0 &&
    customComponents.includes(cursorPosition.prevBlock?.type)
  ) {
    postMessage({ shouldPreventDefault: true, prevBlock: cursorPosition.prevBlock });
  } else {
    postMessage({ shouldPreventDefault: false });
  }
}

self.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

sample logs showing that yes the worker and the main thread is connected and inspite of the worker returning true we're not able to prevent default/stop propogation
2
Editor.jsx:189 true
Editor.jsx:192 prevent default true

Can somebody please help me with it

You're overriding the onmessage handler at every new keystroke, so if by the time a new key is pressed the worker didn't respond yet, your previous handler is lost. One way to handle such a case is to transfer a MessagePort to the worker and send the response from there, so that you can be sure only you will try to listen to that object. See this related answer of mine.

Thanks for the reply looked at your reply, and tried implementing something but it did not work, here is the link -> https://dpaste.org/SVi2S

Oh so you're trying to prevent the default behavior of UI events? These will be long dead when you'll call their preventDefault() and their default would have ran already. Unfortunately there is no easy solution for these. You'd have to always prevent the default behavior and try to replicate it if needed.

so what you're saying is in the FN at the top level itself i should prevent the default behavior, and then based on the workers response, return true or false, i dont think thats the best way.... dont you think it'll mess up the UX and cause a lot of delay/lag. I genuinely need your help in this case please

Well from the look of your few code snippets it's quite hard to see why you need a worker at all in there. But indeed, if you want to prevent an UI event based on the response from a Web Worker you actually need to prevent it before and then reproduce that default behavior if needed. And yes, this may cause some latency issues, which is why we can't tell the event to "wait" for the async process to return a response.
